# How to convert binary payload to JSON key-value pair using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, binary, payload

We want to send IOT data to backend and due to memory limitation we can't use JSON, so we decided to use binary data.
The data will be serialized to have the minimum size, some variables will be only 3 bits, others will be 14 bits based on the max data range.
We thought of having a JSON scheme describe the payload in the backend, but don't know how to map this payload to that scheme, is there an out of the box solution or should we write the conversion? How to start?

This is an example of the scheme.

```
     {
 "message_1": {
      "id" : 1 ,
      "type" : telemetry ,
      "size" : 6 ,
      "version" : 1.1,
      "direction" : Rx ,
    "signal_0":{
        "Id" : 0 ,
        "name": mesage version ,  
        "length" : 8 ,
        "start_bit" : 0 ,
        "type" : "uint8"
    },
    "signal_1":{
        "Id" : 0 ,
        "name": tank depth ,  
        "length" : 32 ,
        "start_bit" : 8 ,
        "type" : float,
    },
    "signal_2":{
        "Id" : 2 ,
        "name": "tank_width" ,  
        "length" : 4 ,  
        "start_bit" : 39 ,
        "type" : "uint8",
    },
   "signal_3":{
        "Id" : 3 ,
        "name": "tank_width" ,  
        "length" : 4 ,  
        "start_bit" : 43 ,
        "type" : "uint8",
    },
 },
  "message_2": {
      "id" : 2 ,
      "type" : "telemetry" ,
      "size" : 3 , 
      "version" : 1.1,
      "direction" : "Rx" ,
    "signal_1":{
        "Id" : 3 ,
        "name": "tank_depth" ,  
        "length" : 8 ,
        "start_bit" : 0 ,
        "type" : "uint8",
    },
    "signal_2":{
        "Id" : 4 ,
        "name": "tank_width",  
        "length" : 4 ,  
        "start_bit" : 8 ,
        "type" : "uint8",
    },
   "signal_3":{
        "Id": 5 ,
        "name": "tank_width" ,  
        "length" : 11 ,  
        "start_bit" : 12 ,
        "type" : "uint8"
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why are you making a JSON scheme for something that's not JSON? Your JSON is not valid (attributes must be quoted, as should string values, no comments are allowed). How are you planning on using the scheme?

Comment: Take a look at https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers It seems like this would be a nice fit for you and you should avoid doing all this stuff by your own. Maybee its small enough.

Comment: Sorry for the JSON mistakes I will fix them.
The scheme is the way that JavaScript should use to map the binary payload to the key-value JSON.
The payload will have a version, so in case we changed the payload structure in new devices we just update the backend with the new one and we should be able to convert to  either of them.